# Race times not formatting correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I do triathlons (short ones). For each race I get 6 results:

- `mm:ss` for the swim
- `mm:ss` for the transition between swim and bike
- `mm:ss` for the bike
- `mm:ss` for the transition from bike to run
- `mm:ss` for the run
- `hh:mm:ss.t` for the overall time.

Here are my numbers:

- 14:03
- 3:55
- 43:16
- 1:34
- 33:30
- 1:36:15.6.

When I paste these into Excel, it turns them into date/time values instead of leaving them as elapsed time.  For example, the bike time of `43:03` is converted to `1/1/1900 7:16:00 PM`.

I have tried various format settings including custom, but those seem to affect the output, not the way the numbers are evaluated when I do the paste.

Can I force them to just remain strings when I do the paste or make it turn the numbers into a number of seconds?

Comment: To keep something a string, put a single quote before it.  '14:03

Comment: You can also do them as seconds, but will require conversions in both directions.  Write yourself a function (or search for one, "VBA convert mm:ss to elapsed seconds", or something like that) to convert hh:mm:ss to a number of seconds.  Once you have all the times converted to seconds, you can use them for further computations.

Answer (score 2):

When you paste a string like `43:03` Excel interprets it as `hh:mm`.  To force interpretation as `mm:ss` include a leading hours figure: `0:43:03`.  The underlying value will be converted to a Date Serial number

Then use custom format to display as you want: `[mm]:ss` to force display of minutes >= 60